# Android display an alert

Tags: android, alert

```
  @Override
public void run() {
AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(DashboardActivity.this);
ab.setMessage("invalid deal id or does not belong to the same organization").
setNegativeButton("OK", dialogClickListener).show();
   }
```

when I hit ok alert does not dismiss;
tried 
ab.dismiss()
ab.cancel()

any help?

Comment: what abt dialogClickListern where it is?

Answer (score 0):

```
 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DashboardActivity.this).create();

    alertDialog.setMessage("invalid deal id or does not belong to the same organization");

            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Ok"),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DashboardActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Look at this dialog!")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        //do things
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
```

This works :)